# How can I change the pry/irb console display value for a Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, console, irb, pry

Here's a simple graph node:

```
Node = Struct.new(:value, :children) do
  def initialize(value, children=[]); super; end
end
```

Frequently I want to look at this in a `pry` or `irb` console. Problem is, when I wire up the graph and look at a node, I get output like this:

```
[1] pry(main)> node
=> #<struct Node
 value=13,
 children=
  [#<struct Node
    value=23,
    children=
     [#<struct Node:...>,
      #<struct Node
       value=19,
       children=[#<struct Node:...>, #<struct Node value=10, children=[#<struct Node:...>]>]>]>,
   #<struct Node value=28, children=[#<struct Node:...>]>,
   #<struct Node value=2, children=[#<struct Node:...>]>,
   #<struct Node value=14, children=[#<struct Node:...>]>]>
```

etc.

This quickly gets out of hand and hard to read. I can define a more readable `to_s` on Node:

```
def to_s; "<#{value} #{children.collect(&:value)}>"; end
```

But I still need to call `puts node` to see this:

```
[1] pry(main)> puts node
<13 [23, 28, 2, 14]>
=> nil
```

Just typing `node` in the console gives me the original verbose output (in both `pry` and `irb`). It's annoying to type `puts` every time I want to look at my more compact representation of `node` in the debugger.

Is there some method I can define to override the console display value of an object? (I thought overriding `inspect` would do this, but it doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for (what is being output in pry/irb) is the result of [`Object#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect), so simply [`alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) for `Node`:

```
alias_method :inspect, :to_s
```

if you have already redefined `Node#to_s`, or just:

```
def inspect
  "<#{value} #{children.collect(&:value)}>"
end
```

Also, make sure you don’t have `awesome_print` gem installed.

Comment: Defining `inspect` has no effect on what is printed in the console (unless I use `puts node`, which is what I'm trying to avoid). I do have `awesome_print` installed but it's not loaded in the script in question, so I'd be surprised if that's causing the issue.

Comment: `awesome_print` is being loaded by `pry` and it monkeypatches `inspect` on all the objects.

Comment: Interesting. `irb` is doing the same? I get the same results there. I don't really want to uninstall `awesome_print` — any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Yes. Use `puts node` if you do want to use `awesome_print` or uninstall `awesome_print` if you want to use just `node`. There is no silver bullet.